# RemoteLinkRenderer not working in rails 4?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, will-paginate

Currently i am upgrading my application to rails 4.after upgrading will paginate with RemoteLinkRenderer not working.
without RemoteLinkRenderer (mean without ajax) its working as normal href.

```
code:
<%=will_paginate task_stage_list, :renderer => 'RemoteLinkRenderer', :page_links => true, :previous_label => "Previous",  :next_label =>"Next" %>


and i have helper named remote_link_renderer in helper folder.


class RemoteLinkRenderer < WillPaginate::ViewHelpers::LinkRenderer

  def link(text, target, attributes = {})
    if target.is_a? Fixnum
      attributes[:rel] = rel_value(target)
      target = url(target)
    end
    attributes["data-remote"] = "true"
    attributes[:href] = target
    tag(:a, text, attributes)
  end
end
```